# Android Studio - Parse JSON Keys

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a local json file. With the code I have so far I can read all the json however, I cannot return each individual key.

Json file (level.json)

```
{
    "level1": {
         "artist": "aaaa",
         "title":"new title",
             "year":"1990"
    },
    "level2": {
         "artist": "bbb",
         "title":"new title2",
             "year":"1992"
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is to get for each level the key. For example I want to get "artist" from "level1".

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("level.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

When I print the function I get all the json.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
text.setText(object.getString("level1"));
```

How can I get the keys depending of each json object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for instance:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(your_json_string);
JSONObject level1 = object.getJSONObject("level1");
JSONObject level2 = object.getJSONObject("level2");
```

and now you can access artist, title and year like that:

```
text.setText(level1.getString("artist"));
text.setText(level1.getString("title"));
text.setText(level1.getString("year"));
```